# How get the attributes list from a feature in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, fields-attributes

I'm getting a vector layer from a WMS server, but I don't know which fields are included in it.  In previous version feature object had a attributes collection but I can't find it now.

Is there a way of searching for feature attributes?

Right now I can use `Feature.get('Name')` and can get the value, but only if I know 'Name' is an attribute. Now imagine I do find a [Name] field or something similar.

Is possible do a  `getFeaturesByAttribute('Name', strName);`

Also available in previous version. But can't find it in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 6):

[getKeys()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Collection.html#getKeys) or [getProperties()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Collection.html#getProperties) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

For my application, I wanted to show attributes of polygon feature as a tooltip and I used following code to get attributes.

```
var info = $('#ttt');

info.tooltip({
    animation: false,
    trigger: 'manual'
});

var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
    var currentZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });

    if (feature !== highlight) {...}
    info.css({...});

    if (feature) {
        var att = feature.getProperties();
        var attStr = att.p_id + "\n" + att.pname +
                    "\n" + att.area +
                    "\n" + att.perimeter + "\n";

        info.tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', attStr)
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
    } else {
        info.tooltip('hide');
    }
};

$(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent));
});

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        info.tooltip('hide');
        return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
    displayFeatureInfo(map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent));
});
```

for style of tooltip:

```
#ttt {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.tooltip.in {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {border-top-color: white;}
.tooltip-inner {border: 2px solid white;}
```

and finally add tooltip:

```
    <div id="map" class="map">
        <div id="ttt"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
findbyfid: function(fid) {
                //Get all vector layers to search FID
                var alllayers = app.olmap.getLayers();
                if (alllayers.length === 1) {   //1 bcos atleast one tile layers is there.
                    alert("Please select vector layers on legend");
                    return;
                }

                alllayers.forEach(function(layer,i) {
                    if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
                        var prop = layer.getProperties();
                        var src = layer.getSource();
                        src.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
                            var att = feature.get("mt_fid");
                            if (att == fid) {
                                var dataExtent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
                                var view = app.olmap.getView();
                                view.fitExtent(dataExtent, (app.olmap.getSize()));
                                highlight.addFeature(feature);
                                return;                                
                            }
                        })

                    }

                }) 
            }
```